# What can Fist of Unbroken Air be used for?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, class-feature

I was wondering, what are the limits of Fist of Unbroken Air in D&D 5e?

Like, does the 10ft push apply to all size categories? If I'm trapped in a cave-in or under an avalanche, can I use it to blow a hole so I can escape? If so, how big is the hole? Can I use it to blow back a thrown weapon, as a readied action?

These are just some of the questions in my head.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Fist of Unbroken Air* says that it targets a **creature**.
As it doesn't specify that it only works on creatures of size category *X* or larger/smaller, it applies to all creatures of any size.

Also since it targets a **creature**, as per RAW, you can't use it to blow out a hole in a cave or avalanche or blow back a thrown weapon.

Note though that monks get the *deflect missiles* class feature at 3rd level which allows them to potentially catch and make a ranged attack with the object as a reaction.

Comment: This power is a good candidate for a DM going beyond RAW and letting you use it to (for example) get advantage on a pull to escape a cave-in or disadvantage an attack on you.